# Replacing certain values in a column with words

Tags: r, dataframe

My goal is to replace a specific column's numeric values into certain words based off of a range to use in a future categorical test. Im trying to change this dataframe below:

Lets call this data frame as DF

| SubjectID | ColumnA | ColumnB | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subject1 | 38 | 2.3 | 2.1 |
| Subject2 | 12 | 2.1 | 2.0 |
| Subject3 | 1 | 1.1 | 1.9 |
| Subject4 | 34 | 3.2 | 1.5 |
| Subject5 | 1 | 1.7 | 1.5 |
| Subject6 | 56 | 3.9 | 1.7 |

To achieve a dataframe such as the one here:

| SubjectID | ColumnA | ColumnB | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subject1 | Mid | 2.3 | 2.1 |
| Subject2 | Low | 2.1 | 2.0 |
| Subject3 | Low | 1.1 | 1.9 |
| Subject4 | Mid | 3.2 | 1.5 |
| Subject5 | Low | 1.7 | 1.5 |
| Subject6 | High | 3.9 | 1.7 |

So in this case, I want to only change columnA's value names based off of a specific range the data values lie in.

**For this example:**
A value of Low represents a value lower than 30.
A value of Mid represents a value between 30 and 50
A value of High represents a value higher than 50

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- DF %>%
    mutate(ColumnA = case_when(ColumnA < 30 ~ "Low", 
        between(ColumnA, 30, 50) ~ "Mid", TRUE ~ "High"))
DF
  SubjectID ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1  Subject1     Mid     2.3     2.1
2  Subject2     Low     2.1     2.0
3  Subject3     Low     1.1     1.9
4  Subject4     Mid     3.2     1.5
5  Subject5     Low     1.7     1.5
6  Subject6    High     3.9     1.7
```

---

Another convenient option without doing multiple expressions is `cut` from `base R`

```
cut(DF$ColumnA, breaks = c(-Inf, 30, 50, Inf), labels = c("Low", "Mid", "High"))
[1] Mid  Low  Low  Mid  Low  High
Levels: Low Mid High
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject1", "Subject2", "Subject3", 
"Subject4", "Subject5", "Subject6"), ColumnA = c(38L, 12L, 1L, 
34L, 1L, 56L), ColumnB = c(2.3, 2.1, 1.1, 3.2, 1.7, 3.9), ColumnC = c(2.1, 
2, 1.9, 1.5, 1.5, 1.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a `base R` solution you can use nested `ifelse`:

```
DF$ColumnA <- ifelse(DF$ColumnA < 30, "Low",
                     ifelse(DF$ColumnA >= 30 & DF$ColumnA <= 50, "Mid", "High"))
```

Result:

```
DF
  SubjectID ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1  Subject1     Mid     2.3     2.1
2  Subject2     Low     2.1     2.0
3  Subject3     Low     1.1     1.9
4  Subject4     Mid     3.2     1.5
5  Subject5     Low     1.7     1.5
6  Subject6    High     3.9     1.7
```